# Is there any example of a physical theory which isn't invariant under translations?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, field-theory, covariance, diffeomorphism-invariance

Isn't it trivial that all physical theories in spacetime are invariant under *local translations*?  Is there an example of a theory which isn't invariant under translations?

Please, take note that I'm not talking about homogeneous metrics, i.e. isometry under translations.  I'm considering general theories of some physical laws defined on spacetime.  Physical laws should stay the same everywhere in spacetime, or else they cannot be called "laws".

If invariance under local translations is a triviality, can it be linked to *invariance under diffeomorphisms*, which can be interpreted as a reformulation of *general covariance*?

Comment: How about theories on manifolds with boundary?

Comment: Can you translate through an event horizon?

Comment: @A.V.S., if the manifold has a boundary, I guess that the translations should cancel at the boundary.  Even if there's a boundary, the physical laws should also be the same everywhere on the manifold and stay invariant under translations up to the boundary.

Comment: A theory with external sources will not be invariant under translations.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform, I'm not sure of this.  If the exterior source acts everywhere, even if it's a varying field, the laws should stay the same everywhere, so you still gets invariance under local translations.  Or isn't?  I don't see how a physical theory (even with boundaries and exterior sources) cannot be trivially invariant under translation.  By definition, a "law" is the same at every point in space and in time.  Can you imagine a "law" that changes from one place to another (in space and/or in time) ?

Comment: What about Bravais lattices?

Answer (score 2):

First, 
in response to comments by OP I would like to emphasize that 'theory' is not necessarily an all-encompassing 'theory of everything', generally a theory would have external objects not described by it.

With this in mind, an answer to the title question would be 'sure'. Just start with a theory that is invariant under translations and break this symmetry.

This could be done by introducing objects (fields, sources, etc.) external to the theory that break such invariance.
For example, we could start with the Standard Model and introduce time dependence of its parameters (so that they would now vary on a cosmological timescales). This new theory no longer has time translation invariance, but is potentially testable as we could look for geological evidence or astronomical observations of these variations. Of course, we then could attempt to 'restore' invariance with respect to time translations by building a new, more universal theory and attributing this variations to a new dynamical field, describing its dynamics in a time invariant fashion. A review of the type of theories could be found here:

- Uzan, J. P. (2003). *The fundamental constants and their variation: observational and theoretical status*. Reviews of modern physics, 75(2), 403, [doi](https://doi.org/10.1103/RevModPhys.75.403), [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0205340).

Another example of breaking translational symmetries is an [orbifold construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbifold#Orbifolds_in_string_theory) in string theory.  By considering quotient of a manifold by a finite group we break manifold's symmetries, and thus an orbifold would have its own string theory, in particular because there are now new degrees of freedom associated with orbifold's singular points.

Comment: Since we always could introduce a "new" field variable to absorb the external field, and restore the translational invariance, isn't translation invariance trivial?

Comment: However, if the new field isn't dynamical (*exterior* source, *fixed background* structure, ...), then we could measure its components to deduce our absolute position on the manifold.  This feature appears to be against the translation invariance idea, which implies that every point of the manifold is "equivalent" to formulate the physical laws, and that we shouldn't be able to know our absolute position by local observations.

Comment: *Since we always could introduce a "new" field variable to absorb the external field*… then this would be a new 'extended theory'. Moreover, introducing new dynamical measurable field by itself is a highly nontrivial task as this must be done consistently and without breaking already established parts of the existing theory.

Comment: @Someone: *This feature appears to be against the translation invariance idea*, yes, if we break translation invariance then *obviously* we would find features incompatible with translation invariance. And this *idea* of TI is not an immutable absolute law, but something that should be questioned and verified.

Comment: I believe that any physical theory *should* have TI built in.  Unless proved otherwise, there isn't any "center" in the universe, and all of its points are equivalent.  We shouldn't be able to find our "absolute" position on the manifold (unless the manifold has some boundary).  This implies that there shouldn't be any fixed background structure or exterior field, and that everything should be dynamical.  I think (I'm not sure yet) that local TI is equivalent to *diffeomorphism invariance*.

Comment: *I believe that any physical theory should have TI built in* While this might be a good feature to have in a 'theory of everything' this may not be a feature of 'narrower' theories even those that are predictive/falsifiable. Also local TI  in not equivalent to diffeomorphism invariance since the latter implies smooth structure which at fundamental level (ToE/Planck  scale) may not exist at all.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some possibilities in addition to the ones in AVS's answer: --

Physical theories don't even have to have spatial degrees of freedom, e.g., a spin glass.

You could also have a theory in which there are spatial degrees of freedom, but they're discrete. E.g., I think spin foams might qualify.

I suppose it's debatable or a matter of semantics whether general relativity has translational invariance. There certainly isn't any such thing as a translation operator (infinitesimal or finite) that can be applied to a solution of the field equations to give a new solution.

Comment: AFAIK, *active coordinates transformation* (or diffeomorphisms) gives a new solution to the field equations.

Comment: @Someone: What you say is true, but there is in general no such thing as a translational diffeomorphism. (And even in cases where there is a diffeomorphism that you want to argue can be interpreted as a translation, the result isn't really a new solution. It's just the same solution in new coordinates.)

Comment: Ben, I agree. However, diffeomorphisms can be interpreted as translations on the manifold, since an active coordinates transformation "slides" a point to a new point on the manifold. In essence, this is a translation. Asking that the equations stays invariant under diffeomorphisms is apparently equivalent as asking that the physics is the same on all points of the manifold.